# At which devices is the 'screen' attribute (CSS media query) applied to?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm only interested in when and on what devices the 'screen' attribute is applied to. For example this:

1) `@media (max-width:632px)`

2) `@media screen and (max-width:632px)`

I know that according to this [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) , 'screen' in #2 means that it applies to devices that support a screen mode, e.g. my PC would display #1 and #2 the same way.

But on what other devices would #2 also apply to? According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) it says:

> "Screen: intended primarily for color computer screens.".

Does this apply to handheld too? Because they've got also a screen (a small screen).  w3.org even says that handhelds have 'screen' too. What about smart watches? They also got a (tiny) screen, right?

I just wonder which computer devices don't have a 'screen' and that needs CSS for formatting content. I mean visuals can only be displayed on a 'screen'. It makes the attribute seem a little bit redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS2.1 actually has a defined `handheld` media type, however, it's been deprecated in [Media Queries Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#media-types) (despite it being a draft, its use should be avoided for future compatibility). If you take a look at the way `screen` is defined in Level 4, it states:

> 'screen': Matches all devices that aren't matched by 'print' or 'speech'.

So I think internally, the drafters realize previous definitions of the types have left a lot of ambiguity as to what the media types actually apply to.

Comment: The handheld media type was intended for devices such as WAP-capable feature phones. Smartphones default to screen and not handheld because their web browsers are advanced enough to handle most cutting-edge web technologies. Nobody makes websites for feature phones anymore, which would explain why handheld is now deprecated.

Comment: Regarding smartwatches: You can still browse webpages with your smartwatch. Would 'screen' also apply to smartwatches as well?

Comment: Wow this is news to me. I'll edit out my last statement. I can't say I understand the smartwatch maker's decision on implementing a full browser in the smartwatch without seriously compromising the battery life, but maybe that's a shortsighted concern as battery capacity seems to advance yearly like other technologies.